# Changing the default WP editor font and size

Tags: wp-editor

The default font is too small and too narrow. Makes editing a pain. I want the default font to be Lucida 16. I am not talking about a pop up menu. I already have that. When I open a new page/post I want Lucida 16 to already be set.

I tried editing admin folder php but I couldn't get it to work. Must be set at very deep level.

Once that is working, then an interface to change on the fly to match font set for web content(set by theme) would be cool.

Comment: You've somewhat lost me there... Are you referring to something like this perhaps? http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_editor_style

Comment: Please accept the answer if it's correct!

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to add support for your theme (if it does not already have it) for editor styles. See this for more information:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_editor_style

Then you'll just need to create a stylesheet. There are some themes out there that already support editor styles, which might be a good place to start in order to know the class names, etc.

Comment: Did not see above person's comment (Cor van Noorloos), didn't mean to repeat.